# How did the mosasaurus stay alive?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

In *Jurassic World*, we meet a mosasaurus. We see it again in *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom*.

[image: Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom, Mosasaurus]

At the start of the film, it's still in its enclosure. How did it survive all that time? While it was fed daily when the park was operating, and it had an Indominus Rex carcass to feed on, it was left alone for a couple of years.

**How did it survive?**

Comment: It's worth noting that the opening of Fallen Kingdom takes weeks or a month, rather than 2 years, after the end of the first film. [Jurassic World Fallen Kingdom Spoiler Special ft. J.A. Bayona & Colin Trevorrow]https://soundcloud.com/empiremagazine/jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom-spoiler-special-ft-ja-bayona-colin-trevorrow)

Comment: @Longshanks is that so? I recall the submarine not worrying about anything large being left alive in the bay. Hm... worth a question.

Comment: Yeah, he went on to say, “The opening sequence is set just after [Jurassic World]. There’s three years that pass [between the events of JW and the events after the opening of JW:FK]. We didn’t put that type up onto the screen, *but the opening scene could even be weeks after or a month after*, and then time passes to allow them to create [the Indoraptor]”

Comment: @Longshanks You may want to put that into an answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/203466/58193).

Comment: I didn't watch the movie but how do we know it's the same reptile?

Comment: @Renan it's in the same enclosure / lagoon, the doors to which haven't been opened until the opening scene of _Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom_.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the film Jurassic World we see the mosasaurus jump out of the water to catch a pteranodon as well as beaching itself to catch the i-Rex™.

Presumably it can simply keep doing that whenever it gets hungry. There's apparently no shortage of dinos (both flying and non) left on the island at the end of the film.

---

Colin Trevorow seems to have confirmed this idea in a podcast interview with Empire Magazine

> **Empire:** *The mosasaurus. I have to ask, what has it been eating, because this movie is set like four or five years….*
>
> **CT:** *Well, but the opening sequence is set just after, there’s three years that pass. We didn’t put that type up onto the screen but the opening sequence could even be weeks after or a few months after. And then time passes to allow them to create that creature*
>
> **Empire:** ***I was trying to work out if the mosasaurus was jumping up and eating birds...***
>
> **CT:** ***Probably some. I think if some nesting pteranadons were on the water and if an animal came down to drink and didn’t realise it was salt-water, they’re in trouble***
>
> <sub><sup>[Jurassic World Fallen Kingdom Spoiler Special ft. J.A. Bayona & Colin Trevorrow](https://soundcloud.com/empiremagazine/jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom-spoiler-special-ft-ja-bayona-colin-trevorrow)</sup></sub>

Comment: One would expect the water to become quite foul after the pumps and filtration system shut down or broke.

Comment: @Xantec - Given that it's an island you'd expect the influx and outflux to be tidal. Just a big tube that runs from a (the sea) to b (the enclosure) with an enormous grate to stop the exhibit from escaping

Comment: Could do that I suppose. I wonder how long it would remain a viable filtration system, before the grate became too clogged.

Comment: @Xantec - Assuming the grate had a big enough diameter, almost indefinitely.

Comment: There's a quote in [this podcast](https://soundcloud.com/empiremagazine/jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom-spoiler-special-ft-ja-bayona-colin-trevorrow) with Empire magazine, where Colin Trevor confirms that it would have eaten birds, as well as 'animals that came down to drink and didn't realise it was saltwater.' 47 minutes in.

Comment: @Longshanks that'll answer my question; may I invite you to add it as an answer here?

Comment: @Longshanks - Indeed. Worthy of its own answer if you want to post it. Failing that, I'm happy to transcribe the podcast and add it to my answer.

Comment: @Valorum - As the question is more about the food available, and your answer is confirmed by Colin (with the minor addition about animals coming for a drink), I thought it might be better incorporated into your answer. Happy for you to go for it!

Comment: @Longshanks - Nice. I've added a transcript of the podcast and a link. Great find.

Answer (score 6):

I've raised mega predators and an animal such as the alligator gar can actually go about two and a half years without eating before it will finally die.

I had an animal shelter and individuals that wanted to see it shut down kill the power and many of the animals. Death the alligator gar was one that survived but the trauma of the event was enough that it never ate again I made several attempts over two and a half years and I think it may have consumed once or twice a small meal but essentially went without eating for two and a half years. 
I have a ball python that refuse to eat for 10 months and then suddenly started to feed again normally. 
And I've heard of large snakes and crocodilians going over a year for an animal as massive as the mosasaurus I would think that you're probably talking about years pending that nothing exhausted its energy reserves.