# How long after Jurassic World was the opening scene of Fallen Kingdom set?

Tags: jurassic-park, jurassic-world, jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom

In the opening scene of *Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom*, we see a submarine crew discovering their submarine is not the largest thing in the bay. They weren't worried about that initially, figuring that there wasn't anything large left alive in the bay.

> "Relax. Anything in here'd be dead by now."

**How long after the events in *Jurassic World* did this scene take place?**

In my [question about the Mosasaurus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/189378/19561) I assumed it to be several years, but a comment on that question asserted it to be a couple of months. So is there any canonical time frame?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Weeks or a month

Colin Trevor discussed this in the Empire podcast: [Jurassic World Fallen Kingdom Spoiler Special ft. J.A. Bayona & Colin Trevorrow](https://soundcloud.com/empiremagazine/jurassic-world-fallen-kingdom-spoiler-special-ft-ja-bayona-colin-trevorrow) (47 minutes in)

He was asked, *'What has the Mosasaurus been eating?*:

> The opening sequence is set just after [Jurassic World]. There’s three years that pass [between the events of JW and the events *after the opening* of Jurassic World: Fallen Kingdom]. We didn’t put that type up onto the screen, **but the opening scene could even be weeks after or a month after**, and then time passes to allow them to create [the Indoraptor]”

Comment: That may answer my original question as well, by the way. Still weird that the crew assumed everything to be dead, though.

Comment: they probably either did not know that the Mosasaurus existed, or they assumed it had run out of food.